# function of a circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have see the following circuit , and i'm actually the first time see an op-amp with negative feed-back with both of the ports has not gronded ! :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f432e0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JYelton , what does this circuit do , or the relation between input and output

Comment: Did you assemble that schematic correctly? There is no resistance on the non-inverting terminal nor at the inverting terminal isolating the sources from the inputs. With negative feedback I am not quite sure what will happen because theory tells us that the op-amp will drive the output such that the difference between the inputs is zero, but both are driven by constant voltages.

Comment: I suspect that it is drawn incorrectly considering you have two series resistances in the feedback. Was one intended to be at the input effectively making this a [inverting amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Inverting_amplifier) configuration?

Comment: An ideal op-amp would produce an unimaginably high positive voltage at the output to overcome the infinitesimally small impedance of the V2 voltage source. Probably would destroy the universe, leaving the question (if any) moot. A real op-amp would just saturate the output near the positive supply rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no negative feedback and more importantly there is no question.

For the first part, I suspect you meant to couple the junction of R1 and R2 to the inverting input of the op-amp (with the other side of R2 going to the 4V source).

And for the 2nd part I suspect your question might be how does this work and what is the output voltage. If so, then the answer is found by always assuming that the voltage on the two inputs are equal and set by the voltage on +Vin. This means there has to be +5V on -Vin and the only way that can happen is when there is 1 volt across R2.

This means there is 10mA flowing through R2 and this current also flows through R1. 10mA through R1 means there is 10V across R1. Given that one side of R1 is 5V, this means the output voltage is +15 volts.

Comment: You're right, I suppose with constant voltages driving the inputs then there wouldn't be any negative feedback. I commented above that I was unsure about this configuration regarding what would happen. If the inputs are constantly driven then of course they can't be changed. I suppose the output would just rail to VCC (positive supply) in this case. `Vout = A(V+ - V-) > 0` where A is open-loop-gain.